# How to use a async dispatch method as a RefreshIndicator onRefresh callback

Tags: redux, dart, flutter, redux-thunk

I have a list wrapped in an `RefreshIndicator`. When the list is pulled down, I want to grab some data from Firestore (a database), update my state, and then render the list.

I have a redux action wired up that can get the data and update my state:

```
final FetchPostsRequest = () {
    return (Store<AppState> store) {
        final CollectionReference postCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("posts");
        postCollection.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
            List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.documents;
            print("Getting documents....");
            List<Model.Post> posts = docs.map((d) => Model.Post.fromMap(d.data)).toList();
            store.dispatch(new FetchPostsSuccess(posts: posts));
        }).catchError((err) {
            print(err);
            store.dispatch(new FetchPostsFailure(error: err));
        });
    };
};
```

How can I use this as the [RefreshIndicator's](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) callback? It's callback is of the form `Future<Null> RefreshCallback ()`, and I'm not sure how to wrangle this to fit into the redux state management mindset.

Answer (score 2):

For using `RefreshIndicator` with redux in Flutter you should put a `Completer<Null>` into your Action class.
The plan is

1. Create an Action that contains a `Completer<Null>`
2. Return the `action.completer.future` to the `onRefresh` function of the `RefreshIndicator`
3. Write a Middleware that listens for this action.

### Action

Let's assume that you have `RefreshItemsAction`. The code will be as follows:

```
class RefreshItemsAction {
  final Completer<Null> completer;

  RefreshItemsAction({Completer completer})
    : this.completer = completer ?? Completer<Null>();
}
```

### Middleware

Than the middleware will be as follows:

```
List<Middleware<AppState>> createItemsMiddleware() {
  return [
    TypedMiddleware<AppState, RefreshItemsAction>(_refreshItems),
  ];
}

Middleware<AppState> _refreshItems() {
  return (Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) {
    if (action is RefreshItemsAction) {
      loadItems().then((items) {
          store.dispatch(ItemsRefreshedAction(items));
          action.completer.complete();
        },
      ).catchError((_) {
        store.dispatch(ItemsNotRefreshedAction());
        action.completer.complete();
      });
    }
    next(action);
  };
}
```

### RefreshIndicator

The Presentation layer will be as follows:

```
return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        var action = RefreshItemsAction();
        store.dispatch(action);
        return action.completer.future;
      },
      child: ListView(...)
    );
```

For more info check [issue on github](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/6)